# Permutation for specified range for only those numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding and i have managed to get a code going that will make a list like i want below except the only problem is that it does every integer. Every time i try to set it to go off of the range it doesnt run, so i am a bit stumped, but am heading in the right direction.

```
Sub Perm()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim u As Integer
    u = Range("E1")
    Debug.Print u
        For a = Range("E1") To Range("E16")
            For b = Range("E1") To Range("E16")
                Cells(u, 1).Value = a
                Cells(u, 2).Value = b
                u = u + 1
            Next b
        Next a
End Sub
```

so far i have thise code which works in giving me what i need but it does all integers instead of only for example 100, 102, 104, 106.
what i am trying to do now is get it to spit out the following

```
100 102
100 104
100 106
102 104
102 106
104 106
```

Comment: The search term you're looking for is [permutations](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+permutations).

Comment: I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do but a loop inside of another loop is called a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you @Comintern that is the term i was looking for! Time to see if i can get this working